# Retreving specific index from array in CakePHP

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have an array and I would to break it up with out using a `foreach` loop. I have a query like this:

```
$pending = $this->Article->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Article.status' => 'pending'),
    'order' => array('Article.created' => 'desc'), 'limit' =>5
));
```

Now this brings me back the most recent 5 articles. What I would normally do here is just loop through them and display them, but I want to grab the specific fields for each index separately. How exactly do I do this?

I assumed it was something like:

```
<?php
   echo $this->Html->link($pending['Article'['title'],array('controller'=>
  'articles','action'=>'view',$pending['Article']['id'][0]));?>
```

Where I just add the index to the end of the field I want for that specific element. This doesn't return the right data. How can I do this?

**UPDATE**:
I was able to figure this out, to grab the specific index from an array in cakephp, you just put the index after your array variable so in this case it would be:
`<?php
       echo $this->Html->link($pending[0]['Article'['title'],array('controller'=>
      'articles','action'=>'view',$pending[0]['Article']['id']));?>`

This will go the the numbered index and allow you to grab any part of the array you would like.

Comment: It doesn't work because that's not how arrays in php work. `debug($pending);` and the answer should be pretty obvious. if you're doing nothing else, with `$pending`, `find('list'` is more appropriate.

Comment: I was going to write pretty much what AD7six wrote, use `find('list'`

Comment: ok so I can just do `$pending = $this->Article->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Article.status' => 'pending'),
    'order' => array('Article.created' => 'desc'), 'limit' =>5
)); ` What would the syntax be for pulling out the specific index?

Comment: Whoops I what I actually wanted to say: `$pending = $this->Article->find('list', array( 'conditions' => array('Article.status' => 'pending'), 'order' => array('Article.created' => 'desc'), 'limit' =>5 ));`